# std::ifstream behaves weirdly with temporary std::string() as constructor argument

Tags: c++

I try to compile simple program

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream strings(std::string(argv[1]));
    std::string line;
    while (!strings.eof()) {
        strings >> line;
    }
}
```

and get peculiar error:

```
error: request for member ‘eof’ in ‘strings’, which is of non-class type ‘std::ifstream(std::string*) {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>(std::basic_string<char>*)}’
```

if I change to

```
std::ifstream strings(argv[1]);
```

all compiles well.

What happens here? Compiler is gcc 4.7 and 4.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sometimes known as the *most vexing parse*: the declaration of `strings` is interpreted as a function declaration, taking a pointer (expressed as an array) as its argument. To make this clearer, I'll remove some parentheses which are redundant in a function declaration:

```
std::ifstream strings(std::string argv[1]);
```

which, by the ancient rules of array/pointer confusion, is equivalent to

```
std::ifstream strings(std::string * argv);
```

which matches the type mentioned in the error message.

Since C++11, you can resolve this using brace-initialisation:

```
std::ifstream strings{std::string(argv[1])};
                     ^                    ^
```

In historical dialects, you would need more verbosity:

```
std::ifstream strings = std::ifstream(std::string(argv[1]).c_str());
```

Note that, before C++11, you couldn't pass a `std::string` directly to the constructor, but would need `c_str()` to get a C-style string.

As you say, you can simply pass `argv[1]` as the argument in any C++ dialect, avoiding the vexatious parse entirely.